# How to group nearby latitude and longitude and assign a Name/Number to that group in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, cluster-analysis

I have a table with `ID`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `COUNTRY_CD` and I am trying to group (clustering) `ID` together within 40 meters and assign a Name/Number to that group. Ex. there are 7 ID from below records are within 40 meters distance and need to assign a Name/Number.

My table has 100 K records of latitude, longitude around the world and there will be more than 100 clusters from a country and I do not know how many clusters will be there in each country.

I am fine to picking up chains of nearby points Ex, ID1 and ID3 are both 'close' to ID6 (but not each other).

```
create table #temp
(
    ID varchar(10),
    LATITUDE [decimal](11, 8),
    LONGITUDE [decimal](11, 8),
    COUNTRY_CD [char](2)
)

insert into #temp select 'ID1', 10.81583689, 78.61898689, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID2', 10.81513789, 78.61898789, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID3', 10.81514889, 78.61894889, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID4', 10.81523989, 78.61898989, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID5', 10.81521089, 78.61891089, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID6', 10.81551189, 78.61891189, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID7', 10.81551189, 78.61791189, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID8', 10.81561189, 78.61792189, 'IN'
insert into #temp select 'ID9', 10.81571189, 78.61793189, 'IN'

select                    
    t1.ID, t2.ID,
    t1.LATITUDE, 
    t1.LONGITUDE,
    t1.COUNTRY_CD,
    --calculate the distance in meters
    cast(6378137.0 * sqrt(power((radians(t1.LATITUDE) - radians(t2.LATITUDE)), 2) 
         + power((radians(t1.LONGITUDE) - radians(t2.LONGITUDE)) * cos(radians(t1.LATITUDE)), 2)) as integer) as MAPPING_DISTANCE,
    (row_number() over (partition by t1.ID order by
              --rank the distance in meters
              cast(6378137.0*sqrt(power((radians(t1.LATITUDE)-radians(t2.LATITUDE)),2) 
              + power((radians(t1.LONGITUDE)-radians(t2.LONGITUDE))*cos(radians(t1.LATITUDE)),2)) as integer) asc
              )) as DISTANCE_RANK
from  
    (select 
         ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, COUNTRY_CD
     from   
         #temp) t1
--join the above list of ID to get near by ID
inner join 
     (select
          ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, COUNTRY_CD
      from  
          #temp) t2 on t1.COUNTRY_CD = t2.COUNTRY_CD
                    --this brings ID available in 75 meters radius
                    and (t2.LATITUDE between (t1.LATITUDE - 0.00056) and (t1.LATITUDE + 0.00056))
                    and (t2.LONGITUDE between (t1.LONGITUDE - 0.00076) and (t1.LONGITUDE + 0.00076))    
                    --distance between t1 co-ordinates and t2 co-ordinates in meters
                    and (cast(6378137.0*sqrt(power((radians(t1.LATITUDE)-radians(t2.LATITUDE)),2) + power((radians(t1.LONGITUDE)-radians(t2.LONGITUDE))*cos(radians(t1.LATITUDE)),2)) as integer)) <= 40 --limit to 40 meters
                    and t1.ID != t2.ID     --exclude the same ID
```

The above query is bringing ID that are within 40 meters but I do not know how do filter the ID those are in a cluster?. Ex, 'Cluster_1' ?

Refer this image [2 clusters from above 9 ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBMrp.jpg)

Note that, I will not give any specific coordinate as input but the query has to pick ID within distance automatically from available coordinates in the table.

My expected result as below,

```
ID  LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   COUNTRY_CD  CLUSTER_NAME
ID1 10.81583689 78.61898689 IN  Cluster_1
ID2 10.81513789 78.61898789 IN  Cluster_1
ID3 10.81514889 78.61894889 IN  Cluster_1
ID4 10.81523989 78.61898989 IN  Cluster_1
ID5 10.81521089 78.61891089 IN  Cluster_1
ID6 10.81551189 78.61891189 IN  Cluster_1
ID7 10.81551189 78.61791189 IN  Cluster_2
ID8 10.81561189 78.61792189 IN  Cluster_2
ID9 10.81571189 78.61793189 IN  Cluster_2
```

Any suggestions how to filter ID that are in a cluster ? If there is any other simple way to do this would be great!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're storing the coordinates separately and manually implementing distance calculations rather than using the `geography` data type?

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbelieve my table & logic are implemented 2 years back and coordinates for a ID may change little bit during everyday refresh as coordinates are retrieving from different system. So, I have to calculate the distance everyday and map the ID. If this is possible in `geography` data type, i can also switch. But, how to capture the ID those in a cluster ?

Comment: "I am fine to picking up chains of nearby points" - so if your points were a ring of points 39m apart along the equator, you'd be happy having just one cluster for the whole world?

Comment: @AakashM I am aware of my data and 40 meter may create 10 K clusters(this is the expected result).

Comment: DBSCAN algorithm might fit to my requirement and anyone have idea or provide some initial hint to convert DBSCAN algorithm to SQL query. Pls refer this link for the algorithm [DBSCAN algorithm](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jing/cse601/fa12/materials/clustering_density.pdf)

Comment: SQL Server just is not well suited for this task. Load your data in a real tool such as ELKI, add a cover tree index, cluster. You will be surprised how slow SQL Server is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's create a computed `geography` column that will store the location coordinates. We will use this column to let SQL Server calculate distances for us:

```
ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD Point_Geolocation AS geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(LONGITUDE AS VARCHAR(100))+ ' ' + CAST(LATITUDE AS VARCHAR(100)) +')', 4326) PERSISTED
```

Second, let's create a table of all nearby locations:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Nearby_Points') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nearby_Points
CREATE TABLE #Nearby_Points (
        ID_1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        ID_2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID_1, ID_2)
)

INSERT INTO #Nearby_Points
(
    ID_1,
    ID_2
)
SELECT   t1.ID AS p1_ID
        ,t2.ID AS p2_ID
FROM #temp t1
    INNER JOIN #temp t2
        ON t1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE t1.Point_Geolocation.STDistance(t2.Point_Geolocation) < 40 -- Specify distance criteria here

-- SELECT * FROM #Nearby_Points
```

**Note:** with 100k+ coordinates, we're looking at approx 5 billion calculations: `(100,000 ^ 2) / 2`. The above query might take a while to execute.

Third, let's create a table to store our cluster list:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Clusters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Clusters
CREATE TABLE #Clusters(
    Cluster_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Point_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Cluster_ID, Point_ID)
);

-- This index may improve performance a little
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Point_ID ON #Clusters(Point_ID);
```

Finally, the following code will:

1. create a new cluster for the first point that isn't already in a
   cluster.
2. repeatedly re-scan the cluster table and add additional points to existing clusters, until each cluster contains all points that should belong to it.
3. Go to step 1. above and repeat, until no new clusters are created.

```
DECLARE @Rowcount INT

INSERT INTO #Clusters
(
    Cluster_ID,
    Point_ID
)
SELECT   COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Cluster_ID) FROM #Clusters),0) + 1
        ,MIN(np.ID_1)
FROM #Nearby_Points np
WHERE np.ID_1 NOT IN (SELECT Point_ID FROM #Clusters)
HAVING MIN(np.ID_1) IS NOT NULL

SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @Rowcount > 0
BEGIN

    WHILE @Rowcount > 0
    BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #Clusters
            (
                Cluster_ID,
                Point_ID
            )
            SELECT   Cluster_ID
                    ,Point_ID
            FROM (
                    SELECT   np.ID_2 AS Point_ID
                            ,c.Cluster_ID
                    FROM #Nearby_Points np
                        INNER JOIN #Clusters c
                            ON np.ID_1 = c.Point_ID

                    UNION

                    SELECT   np.ID_1
                            ,c.Cluster_ID
                    FROM #Nearby_Points np
                        INNER JOIN #Clusters c
                            ON np.ID_2 = c.Point_ID
            ) vals
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM #Clusters
                    WHERE Cluster_ID = vals.Cluster_ID
                    AND Point_ID = vals.Point_ID
            )

            SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END


    INSERT INTO #Clusters
    (
        Cluster_ID,
        Point_ID
    )
    SELECT   COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Cluster_ID) FROM #Clusters),0) + 1
            ,MIN(np.ID_1)
    FROM #Nearby_Points np
    WHERE np.ID_1 NOT IN (SELECT Point_ID FROM #Clusters)
    HAVING MIN(np.ID_1) IS NOT NULL

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

And voilà:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Clusters c



|Cluster_ID | Point_ID|
|-----------|---------|
|         1 | ID1     |
|         1 | ID2     |
|         1 | ID3     |
|         1 | ID4     |
|         1 | ID5     |
|         1 | ID6     |
|         2 | ID7     |
|         2 | ID8     |
|         2 | ID9     |
```

Comment: Hi @Serge , its really worked well. Thanks for your query.

Comment: @serge, i am also trying this same concept in oracle. could you plz give any idea?